# Look for a bigger delimiter than \Bigg

Tags: matrices, delimiters

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\left.
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{vmatrix}\middle/\begin{vmatrix}
b_{11}&b_{12}&b_{13}\\
b_{21}&b_{22}&b_{23}\\
b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}\\
b_{41}&b_{42}&b_{43}
\end{vmatrix}
\right.\]
\[
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{vmatrix}\Bigg/\begin{vmatrix}
b_{11}&b_{12}&b_{13}\\
b_{21}&b_{22}&b_{23}\\
b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}\\
b_{41}&b_{42}&b_{43}
\end{vmatrix}
\]
```

The solidus is not fit for matrix. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could scale `/` using `\scalebox{<factor>}{<stuff>}` from the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\[\left.
  \begin{vmatrix}
    a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
    a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
    a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
  \end{vmatrix}\middle/\begin{vmatrix}
    b_{11}&b_{12}&b_{13}\\
    b_{21}&b_{22}&b_{23}\\
    b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}\\
    b_{41}&b_{42}&b_{43}
  \end{vmatrix}
\right.\]
\[
  \begin{vmatrix}
    a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
    a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
    a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
  \end{vmatrix}\scalebox{1.5}{\Bigg/}\begin{vmatrix}
    b_{11}&b_{12}&b_{13}\\
    b_{21}&b_{22}&b_{23}\\
    b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}\\
    b_{41}&b_{42}&b_{43}
  \end{vmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note that this scales `/` both vertically and horizontally, increasing the width of the symbol as well. To minimize this, I've only scaled `\Bigg/`. To see the difference, consider (say) `\raisebox{-2ex}{\scalebox{4.5}{/}}`.

Another alternative could be to rotate a vertical rule by (say) 15 degrees clockwise. For this you could use

```
\rotatebox{-15}{\rule[-1.8\baselineskip]{0.4pt}{4\baselineskip}}
```

The above vertical rule has a fixed width of `0.4pt`, which you can change to your liking.

Answer (score 7):

If you have access to the `mtpro2` package (short for "MathTime Pro II"), you can use the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % note: only "lite" subset of the mtpro2 package is needed
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \PARENS{\begin{matrix}
    a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
    a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
    a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
  \end{matrix}}
  \LEFTRIGHT/.{\PARENS{\begin{matrix}
    b_{11}&b_{12}&b_{13}\\
    b_{21}&b_{22}&b_{23}\\
    b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}\\
    b_{41}&b_{42}&b_{43}
  \end{matrix}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

to produce this output:

[image]

The package's documentation states that delimiters produced with the `\LEFTRIGHT<a><b>` command (where the left and right hand symbols "a" and "b" can be different) can be up to 10 cm (4") tall. As shown in the example, if you need a "delimiter" on only one side, you should use a "." symbol for the other delimiter.

The full mtpro2 package is *not* free. However, the so-called "lite" subset of this package is indeed free of charge and may be downloaded from [this website](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html).

Answer (score 4):

The only problem is that there is no so big slash in the font. If you use `\middle|` or `\middle(` instead, the delimiter will be big enough.

If necessary, scaling as what Werner do, or use a drawing package like `tikz` may help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{vmatrix}
\tikz[baseline]\draw(-1em,-2\baselineskip)--(1em,2\baselineskip);
\begin{vmatrix}
b_{11}&b_{12}&b_{13}\\
b_{21}&b_{22}&b_{23}\\
b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}\\
b_{41}&b_{42}&b_{43}
\end{vmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```