# \left\langle bigger then \Biggl\langle

Tags: beamer, math-mode, scaling, delimiters

I am putting a graphics inside 
`\left\langle .. \right\rangle`, as

```
\left\langle \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{images/lhs.pdf}}}\right\rangle_{av}
```

The problem is, as it seems, for `scale=0.05`, it is using `\[l/r]angle`'s biggest possible size, and if I try to make the graphics bigger, it is not expanding.

I have searched google and stackexchange's older posts, and got [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35061/look-for-a-bigger-delimiter-than-bigg), which suggested to use `scalebox`.

I tried that, as

```
\scalebox{2.0}{\left\langle} \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.105]{images/lhs.pdf}}}\scalebox{2.0}{\left\langle} {\right\rangle}_{av}
```

which ends up in a error:

```
l.113 \end{frame}

? 
! Extra }, or forgotten \right.
\Gscale@box ...scale@y {#2}\setbox \z@ \hbox {{#3}
                                                  }\setbox \tw@ \hbox {\Gsca...
l.113 \end{frame}
```

`l.113` is the `\end{frame}` of my working frame. So, something is missing. Not Sure.

May I get some help?

**EDIT**
As for example,

```
\Biggl\langle \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.105]{images/lhs.pdf}}}\Biggr\rangle_{av}
```

gives

[image: This Picture]

Comment: You can’t put `\left\langle` and `\right\rangle` in separate groups, let alone separate boxes, they always need to come together. Why don’t you try to scale `\Biggl\langle` and `\Biggr\rangle`?

Comment: `\langle` and `\rangle` have a maximum size, the one corresponding to `\Biggl`, at least in the standard Computer Modern fonts.

Comment: I have tried, and thats what I meant when I said "biggest possible size", so, to clarify, `\left\langle` is giving `\Biggl\langle`, and its still small

Comment: you already know that `\Biggl\langle` is the largest you can get, and that `\left` can't be "separated" from `\right`.  so the obvious thing to try is `\scalebox{2.0}{\Bigg\langle}` ans similarly for `\rangle`.  (note that i've left off the final `l` from `Biggl` on the assumption that spacing is the main thing that it affects, and it's better to see what happens with the scaling before trying to fiddle with the spacing.)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

The `scalerel` package allows you to scale up glyphs to meet the size of an object.  The `\scaleleftright{}{}{}` macro mimics what you might have expected from the `\left(...\right)` syntax (but didn't get).  The optional argument to `\scaleleftright` is the maximum allowed width of the scaled delimiter, since scaling a glyph very large without limiting its width often looks too thick in its stroke.  Here, I have limited the width of the scaled angle brackets to 3ex.

I initially show the view without any manipulation, which is what you observed.  Below to the left was my initial fix.  Finally, to the right is taking Heiko's suggestion of using `\Biggl\langle` etc. to minimize the necessary scaling, which will leave the final scaled object not so thick in its stroke.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\centering\( \left\langle \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{hlCr3}}}\right\rangle_{av} \)

\( {\scaleleftright[3ex]{\langle}{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{hlCr3}}}}{\rangle}}_{\textstyle av} \)
\( {\scaleleftright[3ex]{\Biggl\langle}{\vcenter{\hbox{%
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{hlCr3}}}}{\Biggr\rangle}}_{\textstyle av} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\Biggl\langle` and `\Biggr\rangle` could be used to get a smaller scaling factor and thinner lines.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thank you for that suggestion.  Incorporated.